# How can i add the customized slider with previous and next buttons to the view in iphone?

Tags: ios, slider

[image: How can i add this type of slider to the view in iphone?]

In my app i need to display the slider,to scroll the view by view.(page by page).how can i?
I need to disply the slider as above image

Answer (score 0):

You would have to subclass it and initialize it with that image or whatever image you want it to look like.

Comment: Can i take the separate modal class for slider by taking the parent class as UISlider.